# Rails: has_many :through _ids nested?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many

On a single page I might have a single Video and then checkboxes to add multiple dogs to it. Easy enough (as follows)...

View:

```
<%= check_box_tag "video[dog_ids][]", dog.id %>
```

Controller:

```
params[:video][:dog_ids] ||= []
```

But what I can't figure out how to do is have *multiple* videos, each with multiple dogs.

I currently have this:

```
<% @videos.each do |video| %>
  <%= fields_for "item[]", video do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :id, :index => nil %>
    <%= f.text_field :title, :index => nil%>
    <%= f.text_area :body, :index => nil %>

    <% video.dogs.each do |dog| %>
      <%= check_box_tag "item[][video[dog_ids][]]", dog.id %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But when I do that, `dogs_ids` is always `nil` when it's submitted.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a setup with `fields_for "item[]"` and `f.text_field :title, :index => nil` produces:

```
<input id="item__name" name="item[][title]" size="30" type="text" value="vid1">
```

This indicates that the checkbox name should be `item[][dog_ids][]`.
A working example:

```
<% @videos.each do |video| %>
  <%= fields_for "item[]", video do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :title, :index => nil %>
    <% video.dogs.each do |dog| %>
      <%= check_box_tag "item[][dog_ids][]", dog.id %> <%= Dog.name %>
    <% end %>
    <br>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This produces result in params:

```
{"item"=> [
  {"title"=>"vid1", "dog_ids"=>["1", "2"]},
  {"title"=>"vid2", "dog_ids"=>["2"]},
  {"title"=>"vid3", "dog_ids"=>["2", "3"]}
]}
```

Comment: The `fields_for` has to stay (due to the rest of the fields in the form).

Comment: But in your example, you actually do not use the `fields_for` as you have `<%= check_box_tag ...` as opposed to `<%= f.check_box ...`.

Comment: And my point was that you have to specify the video id in the checkbox name and with current code examples, the `item[]` part is unnecessary. Nonetheless I update my code to mirror your example.

Comment: Just updated my original post to show context. `item[]` is necessary because there are multiple videos and I need to update all the form fields with `update_attributes`

Comment: I have to use `check_box_tag` due to the issue mentioned in the Rails docs about array-like parameters: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-check_box I'm assuming that's the error you got. So, your current example still doesn't work.

Comment: @Shpigford: BTW `check_box_tag` is not part of the `fields_for` setup so my first example would have worked too, if only you had shown more code so that I could see there are no indexes. Care to revoke the downvote?